# Running Tensorboard on same port as jupyter lab

Tags: jupyter, tensorboard, jupyter-lab

[This](https://github.com/lspvic/jupyter_tensorboard/) is running jupyter and tensorboard on same port.

I want to do same for jupyter lab, but I am unable to understand how to run both on same port.

Running tensorboard :

> tensorboard --logdir={path to eventfile} --port={port number}